# Visual Studio 2012 deploying workflow

Tags: workflow, deployment, solution-package, visual-studio-2012

I uploaded the wsp file of a visual studio 2012 workflow to galleries->solutions in central admin. The feature appears in manage features on central admin but does not show up in site settings on sites to be activated. Also does not show up on list of workflows.

Comment: Did you check the Site Collection Features ?

Comment: Yes. It is activated from Central Admin's Site collection but still does not show as a workflow option

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link. This is the users' sentiment about VS2012 deployment:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-